# Add gap between outer and inner border of checkbox

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I'm styling a bunch of form elements and need to customize the style of the checkbox. It needs to look like this when checked:

[image]

The closest I can get to that is as you see here: https://jsfiddle.net/ufhav6Lw/2/

```css
.gform_wrapper.gravity-theme .gfield input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + *::before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    margin-right: 0.3rem;
    border-radius: 10%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: #c3cbd6;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
    color: #008ed4;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + *::before {
    content: "";
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    background: #008ed4;
    background-size:50%;
    border-color: #008ed4;
}
```

```html
<div class="gf_browser_chrome gform_wrapper gravity-theme" id="gform_wrapper_4"><div id="gf_4" class="gform_anchor" tabindex="-1"></div>
                        <div class="gform_heading">
                            <h2 class="gform_title">Forms Kitchen Sink</h2>
                            <span class="gform_description">A demo page for the forms styling</span>
                        </div><form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="gform_ajax_frame_4" id="gform_4" action="/forms/#gf_4">
                        <div class="gform_body gform-body"><div id="gform_fields_4" class="gform_fields top_label form_sublabel_below description_below"><div id="field_4_2" class="gfield field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibility_visible"><label class="gfield_label" for="input_4_2">Focused Field (enter text to test the focus style)</label><div class="ginput_container ginput_container_text"><input name="input_2" id="input_4_2" type="text" value="" class="large" aria-invalid="false" style="background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAABHklEQVQ4EaVTO26DQBD1ohQWaS2lg9JybZ+AK7hNwx2oIoVf4UPQ0Lj1FdKktevIpel8AKNUkDcWMxpgSaIEaTVv3sx7uztiTdu2s/98DywOw3Dued4Who/M2aIx5lZV1aEsy0+qiwHELyi+Ytl0PQ69SxAxkWIA4RMRTdNsKE59juMcuZd6xIAFeZ6fGCdJ8kY4y7KAuTRNGd7jyEBXsdOPE3a0QGPsniOnnYMO67LgSQN9T41F2QGrQRRFCwyzoIF2qyBuKKbcOgPXdVeY9rMWgNsjf9ccYesJhk3f5dYT1HX9gR0LLQR30TnjkUEcx2uIuS4RnI+aj6sJR0AM8AaumPaM/rRehyWhXqbFAA9kh3/8/NvHxAYGAsZ/il8IalkCLBfNVAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-size: 16px 18px; background-position: 98% 50%;"> </div></div><div id="field_4_3" class="gfield gfield--width-full gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibility_visible"><label class="gfield_label" for="input_4_3">Field Error (submit empty field to see error styling)<span class="gfield_required"><span class="gfield_required gfield_required_text">(Required)</span></span></label><div class="ginput_container ginput_container_text"><input name="input_3" id="input_4_3" type="text" value="" class="large" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"> </div></div><div id="field_4_4" class="gfield field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibility_visible"><label class="gfield_label" for="input_4_4">Select (choose an option to see selected/focused styling)</label><div class="ginput_container ginput_container_select"><select name="input_4" id="input_4_4" class="large gfield_select" aria-invalid="false"><option value="Choose an option...">Choose an option...</option><option value="First Choice">First Choice</option><option value="Second Choice">Second Choice</option><option value="Third Choice">Third Choice</option></select></div></div><div id="field_4_5" class="gfield field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibility_visible"><label class="gfield_label" for="input_4_5">Text Area (enter text to see text styling)</label><div class="ginput_container ginput_container_textarea"><textarea name="input_5" id="input_4_5" class="textarea large" placeholder="Placeholder" aria-invalid="false" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea></div></div><div id="field_4_7" class="gfield field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibility_visible"><label class="gfield_label" for="input_4_7">Phone (enter number to see text styling)</label><div class="ginput_container ginput_container_phone"><input name="input_7" id="input_4_7" type="text" value="" class="large" placeholder="(XXX) XXX-XXXX" aria-invalid="false"></div></div><div id="field_4_8" class="gfield field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibility_visible"><label class="gfield_label" for="input_4_8">File</label><div class="ginput_container ginput_container_fileupload"><input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="67108864"><input name="input_8" id="input_4_8" type="file" class="large" aria-describedby="gfield_upload_rules_4_8" onchange="javascript:gformValidateFileSize( this, 67108864 );"><span class="gform_fileupload_rules" id="gfield_upload_rules_4_8">Max. file size: 64 MB.</span><div class="validation_message validation_message--hidden-on-empty" id="live_validation_message_4_8"></div></div></div><fieldset id="field_4_9" class="gfield field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibility_visible"><legend class="gfield_label">Radio</legend><div class="ginput_container ginput_container_radio"><div class="gfield_radio" id="input_4_9">
            <div class="gchoice gchoice_4_9_0">
                    <input class="gfield-choice-input" name="input_9" type="radio" value="Radio Select 1" id="choice_4_9_0" onchange="gformToggleRadioOther( this )">
                    <label for="choice_4_9_0" id="label_4_9_0">Radio Select 1</label>
            </div>
            <div class="gchoice gchoice_4_9_1">
                    <input class="gfield-choice-input" name="input_9" type="radio" value="Radio Select 2 with a second line of text" id="choice_4_9_1" onchange="gformToggleRadioOther( this )">
                    <label for="choice_4_9_1" id="label_4_9_1">Radio Select 2 with a second line of text</label>
            </div>
            <div class="gchoice gchoice_4_9_2">
                    <input class="gfield-choice-input" name="input_9" type="radio" value="Radio Select 3" id="choice_4_9_2" onchange="gformToggleRadioOther( this )">
                    <label for="choice_4_9_2" id="label_4_9_2">Radio Select 3</label>
            </div></div></div></fieldset><fieldset id="field_4_10" class="gfield field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibility_visible"><legend class="gfield_label gfield_label_before_complex">Checkbox</legend><div class="ginput_container ginput_container_checkbox"><div class="gfield_checkbox" id="input_4_10"><div class="gchoice gchoice_4_10_1">
                                <input class="gfield-choice-input" name="input_10.1" type="checkbox" value="Checkbox Select 1" id="choice_4_10_1">
                                <label for="choice_4_10_1" id="label_4_10_1">Checkbox Select 1</label>
                            </div><div class="gchoice gchoice_4_10_2">
                                <input class="gfield-choice-input" name="input_10.2" type="checkbox" value="Checkbox Select 2 with a second line of text" id="choice_4_10_2">
                                <label for="choice_4_10_2" id="label_4_10_2">Checkbox Select 2 with a second line of text</label>
                            </div><div class="gchoice gchoice_4_10_3">
                                <input class="gfield-choice-input" name="input_10.3" type="checkbox" value="Checkbox Select 3" id="choice_4_10_3">
                                <label for="choice_4_10_3" id="label_4_10_3">Checkbox Select 3</label>
                            </div></div></div></fieldset><fieldset id="field_4_11" class="gfield field_sublabel_above field_description_below gfield_visibility_visible"><legend class="gfield_label gfield_label_before_complex">Time</legend><div class="ginput_complex">
                        <div class="gfield_time_hour ginput_container ginput_container_time" id="input_4_11">
                            <label class="hour_label" for="input_4_11_1">Hour</label>
                            <input type="text" maxlength="2" name="input_11[]" id="input_4_11_1" value="00" placeholder="HH" aria-required="false"> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="above hour_minute_colon">:</div>
                        <div class="gfield_time_minute ginput_container ginput_container_time">
                            <label class="minute_label" for="input_4_11_2">Minutes</label>
                            <input type="text" maxlength="2" name="input_11[]" id="input_4_11_2" value="00" placeholder="MM" aria-required="false">
                        </div>
                        <div class="gfield_time_ampm ginput_container ginput_container_time above">
                                
                                <select name="input_11[]" id="input_4_11_3">
                                    <option value="am">AM</option>
                                    <option value="pm">PM</option>
                                </select> 
                           </div>
                    </div></fieldset><div id="field_4_13" class="gfield field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibility_visible"><label class="gfield_label" for="input_4_13">Date</label><div class="ginput_container ginput_container_date">
                            <input name="input_13" id="input_4_13" type="text" value="" class="datepicker mdy datepicker_with_icon gdatepicker_with_icon hasDatepicker initialized" placeholder="Pick a date." aria-describedby="input_4_13_date_format" aria-invalid="false"><img class="ui-datepicker-trigger" src="https://hamodia-2021.local.zill.as/wp-content/plugins/gravityforms/images/datepicker/datepicker.svg" alt="Select date" title="Select date">
                            <span id="input_4_13_date_format" class="screen-reader-text">MM slash DD slash YYYY</span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" id="gforms_calendar_icon_input_4_13" class="gform_hidden" value="https://hamodia-2021.local.zill.as/wp-content/plugins/gravityforms/images/datepicker/datepicker.svg"></div></div></div>
        <div class="gform_footer top_label"> <input type="submit" id="gform_submit_button_4" class="gform_button button" value="Submit" onclick="if(window[&quot;gf_submitting_4&quot;]){return false;}  window[&quot;gf_submitting_4&quot;]=true;  " onkeypress="if( event.keyCode == 13 ){ if(window[&quot;gf_submitting_4&quot;]){return false;} window[&quot;gf_submitting_4&quot;]=true;  jQuery(&quot;#gform_4&quot;).trigger(&quot;submit&quot;,[true]); }"> <input type="hidden" name="gform_ajax" value="form_id=4&amp;title=1&amp;description=1&amp;tabindex=0">
            <input type="hidden" class="gform_hidden" name="is_submit_4" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" class="gform_hidden" name="gform_submit" value="4">
            
            <input type="hidden" class="gform_hidden" name="gform_unique_id" value="">
            <input type="hidden" class="gform_hidden" name="state_4" value="WyJ7XCI5XCI6W1wiNGZmZjdiMzNkNzc5ZmFjZDdlZTJjYWRiZmM0ZGQwNzRcIixcIjkyMzk1MmEyOTVkNzYxZTU5NDJmYWNkNmM4N2JhYzE5XCIsXCI4NDEwODYwZGNjZDEyZjM4MjE2YTQ2N2JhMTBmOWQ0NFwiXX0iLCI1YzRjYTFhNjhmOThhN2QzMGFkMDQxMTkwYzU5Nzg2MSJd">
            <input type="hidden" class="gform_hidden" name="gform_target_page_number_4" id="gform_target_page_number_4" value="0">
            <input type="hidden" class="gform_hidden" name="gform_source_page_number_4" id="gform_source_page_number_4" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="gform_field_values" value="">
            
        </div>
                        </form>
                        </div>
```

[image]

I've tried using `background-size:50%;` at line 24 of the CSS in the fiddle.

How do I create the gap between the inner and outer square of the checkbox?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom checkbox using only CSS and HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34712350/custom-checkbox-using-only-css-and-html)

Comment: The most common approach uses a label for the checkbox to give you greater control; see proposed dupe for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways how to do it, for example

```css
input[type='checkbox'] {width: 18px; height: 18px; border: 1px solid #ccc; position: relative; margin: 0; -webkit-appearance: none; -moz-appearance: none; appearance: none; vertical-align: text-bottom;}
input[type='checkbox']:before {content: ''; position: absolute; top: 2px; left: 2px; background: #ccc; width: 12px; height: 12px;}

input[type='checkbox']:checked {border-color: blue}
input[type='checkbox']:checked:before {background: blue}
```

```html
<label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    Checkbox 1
</label>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    Checkbox 2
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I needed, with a few tweaks for default (unchecked) state, color, and gap distance.

Comment: @user3169905 Yes, it was just an example how to do it. The minorities like set the right blue color are up to you :-)